# Tomcat 9 manager/html not found

Tags: tomcat

I would like to ask for some help concerning the Tomcat 9.0.40 manager/html webapp.

The page http://my-server:8080/ shows the Tomcat start page. Ok.
But http://my-server:8080/manager/html leads to a 404. Hmmm...

The conf/tomcat-users.xml contains:

```
<role rolename="manager-gui"/>
<user username="tomcat" password="tomcat" roles="admin-gui,manager-gui,manager-script"/>
```

The conf/Catalina/localhost/manager.xml contains:

```
<Context privileged="true" antiResourceLocking="false"
         docBase="${catalina.home}/webapps/manager">
    <Valve className="org.apache.catalina.valves.RemoteAddrValve" allow="^.*$" />
</Context>
```

The webapp is there:

```
[root@my-server /opt/tomcat-8080/webapps]# ll
insgesamt 69316
drwxr-x--- 15 root root     4096 25. Nov 09:59 docs
drwxr-x---  7 root root       99 25. Nov 09:59 examples
drwxr-x---  6 root root       79 25. Nov 09:59 host-manager
drwxr-x---  6 root root      114 25. Nov 11:15 manager
drwxr-x---  3 root root      223 25. Nov 09:59 ROOT
```

The logs/localhost_access_log.2020-11-25.txt means:

```
192.168.27.86 - - [25/Nov/2020:11:48:47 +0100] "GET /manager/html HTTP/1.1" 404 778
```

Any idea?

Regards
Michael

Answer (score 1):

Argh! I just got it!

As it's the first time I use Tomcat 9, I created the needed context file manager.xml, but the included docBase attribute was not correct. The webapp is not located in ${catalina.home} but in ${catalina.base}.

Unfortunately I didn't saw the log message:

```
25-Nov-2020 12:05:43.674 WARNUNG [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDescriptor Deployment of deployment descriptor [/opt/tomcat-8080/conf/Catalina/localhost/host-manager.xml] with
 an external docBase means the directory [/opt/tomcat-8080/webapps/host-manager] in the appBase will be ignored
```

I seemed to be blind! Sorry!

Solved!